# Passing variables from c++ to PHP

Tags: php, c++

I am trying to pass variables from a c++ app to a php script, which in turn querys a sql database and gives the c++ app back the information.  I figured out how to pass strings from the php script to the c++ app, but I'm having trouble passing the initial argument from the app to the php script.  Right now I am calling the script through:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *p = _popen("C:/xampp/php/php E:/phpFiles/phpTest.php","r");
    char buffer[1024];
    char *line_p = fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),p);
    _pclose(p);
    cout << line_p;
}
```

, which works to get data from php but does not allow for anything to be sent in.  I have a good bit of c++ experience, but am a total newbie when it comes to PHP.   I feel like I should be able to add some arguments when I call `phpTest.php`, I''m just not sure how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you want to do exactly? You want PHP to run queries in DB and return results so your C++ app can read?

Comment: This very obviously depends on how your script expects its parameters. If it reads `$argv`, you just have to append stuff to your program string in `_popen`. You can use a `stringstream` to append stuff easily.

Comment: If all you want to do is to query (My)SQL statements there are definitely better ways to do this, e.g. using the MySQL client library. You should definitely consider that when you want to call it again and again for queries. I once used PHP CLI in a project which turned out to be a huge bottleneck for performance, even if you keep a single PHP process opened for multiple script invocations...

Comment: Why not just write everything in C++or PHP? Both are capable of accessing a database and avoids lots of complications

Comment: Also, you need to (de)serialize data on both sides, e.g. using JSON or something similar, which adds unnecessary complexity to this otherwise simple task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using PHP CLI you can pass arguments to the script by adding the arguments after the file call, separated by a space: `php /path/to/script.php arg1 arg2`

In your PHP script you can use the [`$argv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array to access the provided arguments.

**script.php:**

```
<?php

print_r($argv);

# Output:
Array
(
    [0] => .\script.php
    [1] => arg1
    [2] => arg2
)
```

Keep in mind: `$argv[0]` is always the name of the file you are calling. Your provided arguments will start at `$argv[1]`.

Comment: So if I wanted to put in something like `"SELECT field1 FROM tableA"`, I would just use something like `_popen("php /path/to/script" "SELECT field1 FROM tableA", "r")`?

Comment: Glad you got it working. Yes, you can wrap quotes around text to pass it as a single argument.